# Overenthusiastic use of backticks to emphasize phrases

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm running into random post edits lately that doesn't seem right to me. The editor is adding emphasize on phrases by using code backticks.

I think these edits do not really contribute in improving the post, but that's not all that had me decided to address this here.

Also IMO backticks should be used for inline code references like referencing to a variable `$foo` or a function `bar()` (as also [stated on SE Markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans))

Example, I made the added code spans also bold:

> I've ran a big business on **`Mijoshop for over 2 years`**. Now I'd like to create the same one as it on Magento. I spent **`a lot of money for SEO and  I'm afraid of loosing the URLs in target store.`** Should I use **`Mijoshop to Magento migration tool?`** Please advise me.

SE does not provide any means in discussing this with users mutually, so I'm addressing this here in meta.

Comment: I'd like to bring this to your attention again. I'm seeing post edits being approved that do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rolled back quite a few of these edits when I encountered them or if there were other useful changes, reverted the incorrect backtick usage. I have to admit that I use the inline code style not only for real code but sometimes for things like file names or menu paths like `System > Configuration > Catalog`. But really shouldn't be used for emphasizing.

I wouldn't go so far to remove them from an original post but I don't think one should force this questionable style upon others' answers. If it would come up in the "Suggested Edits" review queue, it would be rejected for not adding value.